# Monaco Editor - add Python language server

Tags: python, intellisense, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I'm trying to add support for intellisense for Python in Monaco Editor. All the examples I found involve using a Python Language Server running on the server and communicating with the frontend using a websocket; however, the TS language server that Monaco runs is run inside of a browser worker, so I'm trying to emulate the same thing for Python.

I took a look at the examples at [this address](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient), but they aren't specific enough for my use case as they are very simple and don't involve running a full-fledged language server.

How can this be done?

Comment: have you tried the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/421) ?

Comment: They are 5 years old and for a much older version of Monaco. I was looking for something that could reliably be used for a more modern version, considering so much has changed since